# Concerned about using a public key in a class to decrypt resources

Tags: memory, security, encryption

I've created a program which stores decryption key in a file, but when I run it, the key is decrypted and stored in a public class where the program can use it in all instances, but I'm concerned about the security of this method because is easy to search and get the key in system memory.

I'm not an expert in security and cryptography, but I want to know if there is a method to protect the key from unauthorized access in system memory.

Comment: It's the classic DRM problem. If you must give someone the lock and the key, eventually they'll find a way to break the "security" because there cannot possibly be any.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much you can do in this situation - if your program can decrypt the key from the file, and this program is run on the client's computer, then the client can go through your program, disassemble it, and find out exactly how it decrypts the key - not to mention finding it in memory. I am not an expert in this, but TPM modules were created to help deal with this problem - they are supposedly secured from client tampering, but then as Scott Chamberlain mentioned, it becomes a question of how to get the key securely into the TPM if you need a specific key.

Comment: You can register a arbitrary key with the TPM and tell it to never disclose the key, even to an administrator (the only operations you can do is give the TPM a blob and it decrypts it for you or erase the key from its stores). The problem is how to get the key in to the TPM in the first place securely.